# Disable scraping of specific endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Using Prometheus we are scraping all our Kubernetes endpoints. Here is our relevant configuration in `prometheus.yaml`:

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-nodes'

  # Default to scraping over https. If required, just disable this or change to
  # `http`.
  scheme: https

  # This TLS & bearer token file config is used to connect to the actual scrape
  # endpoints for cluster components. This is separate to discovery auth
  # configuration because discovery & scraping are two separate concerns in
  # Prometheus. The discovery auth config is automatic if Prometheus runs inside
  # the cluster. Otherwise, more config options have to be provided within the
  # <kubernetes_sd_config>.
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    server_name: kube-worker
    # If your node certificates are self-signed or use a different CA to the
    # master CA, then disable certificate verification below. Note that
    # certificate verification is an integral part of a secure infrastructure
    # so this should only be disabled in a controlled environment. You can
    # disable certificate verification by uncommenting the line below.
    #
    # insecure_skip_verify: true
  bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: node

  relabel_configs:
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)

# Scrape config for service endpoints.
#
# The relabeling allows the actual service scrape endpoint to be configured
# via the following annotations:
#
# * `prometheus.io/scrape`: Only scrape services that have a value of `true`
# * `prometheus.io/scheme`: If the metrics endpoint is secured then you will need
# to set this to `https` & most likely set the `tls_config` of the scrape config.
# * `prometheus.io/path`: If the metrics path is not `/metrics` override this.
# * `prometheus.io/port`: If the metrics are exposed on a different port to the
# service then set this appropriately.
- job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'

  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints

  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
    action: replace
    target_label: __scheme__
    regex: (https?)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    target_label: __address__
    regex: (.+)(?::\d+);(\d+)
    replacement: $1:$2
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_name
```

Somehow all our services are scraped, even if we do not set the `prometheus.io/scrape` to true in the application's `service.yaml`.

Now we do not want to scrape two endpoints. Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: That should work, so something else is going on. Are you sure that's the config file Prometheus is using?

Comment: Yes. We are sure. Somehow ALL endpoints are scraped and shown in our /targets dashboard. Maybe our `blackbox-exporter` is scraping them?